# iOS / Core Data - How can I change sectionNameKeyPath of a NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I declared my fetchedResultsController like this

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];
```

But when I click on a UISegmentedControl, I want to change the sectionNameKeyPath to be @"title".

Do you know a way to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to redefine the FRC and reinitiate the fetch request.  Either set a property on the class to hold the value of the current sectionNameKeyPath (set the default in the viewDidLoad event), or you can pass that in to the method that instantiates and executes the FRC.

Comment: That's what I thought but I was wondering if you could just modify the sectionNameKeyPath like you can do with the fetchRequest. Thanks